# Shared model objects across integration response models in apigateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Say I have 2 response models A and B. A and B shared a common nested object C. (ie A.C.field1 B.C.field1).

As I understand APIGateway today I must define C in the model definition for A and then again for B.

This results in two undesirable outcomes:

1. Totally duplicated json schema (annoying but not impossible to manage).
2. In the generated obj-c (or java) SDK I have two distinct classes A.C and B.C.    This duplication complicates use of the SDK as the two version of C are not the same type.

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=697388 This seems on point but have not yet tested it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your shared model object and refer to it in other models with a *canonical reference*.

Assuming you've defined a common model "C", you could refer to model "C" in models A or B with the following JSON schema:

Model A or B:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "field": { 
        "$ref": "https://apigateway.amazonaws.com/restapis/{{api-id}}/models/C" 
    }
  }
}
```

The generated SDKs will have a common object C.

If your shared object properties are contained to a single Model, you can use an *inline reference* instead:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",

  "definitions": {
    "C": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        ...
      }
    }
  },

  "type": "object",

  "properties": {
    "field": { "$ref": "#/definitions/C" },
    ...
  }
}
```